# Definitions of noncooperative and cooperative games.

Tags: game-theory

These days I have read many descriptions of a noncooperative game like the one below.

A noncooperative game is a game in which players are unable to make enforceable contracts outside of the rules/description of such a game.

As a graduate student majoring in math, I wonder if there is any mathematically formal definition of a noncooperative( and cooperative) game.

Comment: there are plenty of books devoted to game theory, including various formalizations of both cooperative and non-cooperative games.

Comment: @IttayWeiss Due to the minor importance of this area in my university, there are few mathematical game theory textbooks. As you suggested, I have looked up these terms in all these books and found nothing. In these books, they use the descriptions as I wrote in my question. And I guess they're not mathematical definitions, aren't they? Could you please recommend some mathematical textbooks that contain these formal definitions?

Comment: See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooperative_game and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_theory, especially http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal-form_game . I agree with the reference to Osborne and Rubenstein's online text as well.

Answer (score 2):

You can define a cooperative game with n players $A=a_1,a_2,\dots a_n$ to be a a function from the power set of $A$ to $\mathbb R$. The idea is each alliance between players has a value, this value can be viewed as a cost or as a reward.

non-cooperative games are usually harder and have many definitions, you might be interested in the [extensive way](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensive-form_game) to look at games

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will ever find a formal definition. The informal one is very good for all purposes. The closest you can get is the definition of a strategic game (= non-cooperative games) see Osborne and Rubinstein (section 2.1) and the definition of coalitional games with and without transferable payoff ( = cooperative games) see again Osborne and Rubinstein (sections 13.1 and 13.5). By the way, Osborne and Rubinstein are freely available online - to get a copy legally, you only need to register.

Answer (score 0):

Two mathematicians who won Nobel prizes in economics:

1. Nash
2. Shapley

for work in non-cooperative and cooperative game theory respectively. Google and JSTOR are your friends.

Comment: The Nash bargaining solution is cooperative and Shapley's stochastic games are non-cooperative...